# Editing Unicode within a String

Tags: java, unicode

I wanted to have a List with Unicode Strings, but I wondered if I could use a for loop instead of adding 9 variables by hand. I tried the following code, but it didn't work.

```
List<String> reactions = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    reactions.add("\u003" + i + "\u20E3");
}
```

My IDEA gives me an 'illegal unicode escape' error. 
Is there an other way to accomplish this?

Comment: accomplish what? What didn't work?

Comment: @jhamon I edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to convert a number to a character within a string is probably using a Formatter, via [String.format](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...%29):

```
List<String> reactions = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    reactions.add(String.format("%c\u20e3", 0x0030 + i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to display the character \u003i, with `i`from 1 to 9, and \u20E3, remember a character is like a number and can be used in mathematical operation.

- get the character `\u0030`: `'\u0030'`
- add i : `'\u0030' + i`
- concatenate the new character with the other one (as a string)

Then print the result:

```
System.out.println((char)('\u0030' + i) + "\u20E3");
```

Comment: This wouldn't work, it just converts `\u0030` to an integer and then adds `i` to it. `49\u20E3` isn't a valid Unicode Character.

Comment: whoops, missing cast before the sum